# Asking question about Outlook.com

Tags: discussion, questions, closed-questions, reopen-request, on-topic

I asked a question concerning [Outlook.com](https://superuser.com/q/1605757/187169).

As I was not sure whether Superuser was the proper place, I did some research and realised that there is a dedicated tag:
`outlook.com`. The tag is relatively active with 70 questions, including in recent months.
However, my question was considered off-topic and closed.

Note that there is a `gmail` tag which should be as much on topic as Outlook.com.
I also checked in case other accepted questions were about the interaction between Outlook.com and other on-topic software apps, but most of them are about Outlook.com full stop.

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you read the tag description?  “Questions about Outlook.com are off topic on Super User and should be asked at http://webapps.stackexchange.com/.”?  You also didn’t actually specify what your question was in the question body. Questions about Google Mail would also be out of scope at Super User

Answer (score 2):

The [What topics can I ask about here?](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) help page explicitly states that questions about "websites or web services like Facebook, Twitter, and WordPress" are offtopic. Moreover, the [tag description](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/outlook.com) explicitly states that "Questions about Outlook.com are off topic on Super User and should be asked at [http://webapps.stackexchange.com/."](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/.%22) So it's pretty safe to say that Outlook.com is offtopic. Why this tag hasn't been burninated is another question, to which I have no good answer.

Comment: Another question, But a strictly related one, The first thing you do to learn if a potential post is on-topic is to check whether there are similar active questions. If you don't find them, you read the formal list. One does not care to read a lengthy list if there is an `outlook.com` and a `gmail` tag with hundred of active questions.

Comment: @antonio - Except your question was about the web application itself.  The tag description is carefully written to explain what type of Outlook.com questions are within scope.  There are not hundreds of outlook.com questions, there are 70, and almost all of them are unanswered.  The questions that are open are actually about Outlook the desktop client.